# Make spec file OS-version-specific

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

The subpackage "yum-plugin-post-transaction-action" from yum-utils appeared with RHEL6.

Now I have an heterogeneous infrastructure, and I needed this yum plugin for RHEL/Centos 5. So I made a spec file, built the RPM, tested it, it works. But I want to make sure no one builds it for RHEL6 or 7 on the packaging machine by mistake one day, and overriding the vendor-provided one.

I have first thought to look for RPM specific tags like `excludeOS` but they're too wide. We are using mock, but I didn't find a way to configure it for this purpose.

All I did for now is to make the built RPM depend on `centos-release-5` which seems very dirty and doesn't prevent build, only install...

Comment: You'll want to look at a `Build-Requires` entry. That's the only way I can think of to get where you want to go.

Comment: That might be a problem since I'm building everything using mock from a CentOS 7 system, but that may be the only solution =/

Answer (score 2):

```
%build
%if 0%{rhel} > 5
  echo "This package should be build only for RHEL5"
  exit 1
%endif
```